# The query is not giving a desired output which I want

Tags: mysql, sql

**Query with OR which outputs wrong**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sm___employees.id,
    sm___employees.employee_code,
    sm___employees.leaving_date,
    sm___employees.name_of_employee,
    sm___employees.position,
    sm___employees.rating,
    sm___employees.entry_date 
FROM 
    sm___employees 
JOIN 
    sm___employee_skills
ON 
    sm___employees.id=sm___employee_skills.employee_id
WHERE 
    ((sm___employee_skills.skill_id=1 AND sm___employee_skills.ans LIKE '%MBA%') 
    **OR**
    (sm___employee_skills.skill_id=5 AND sm___employee_skills.ans IN (3)))
    AND 
    sm___employees.rating IN (1) 
ORDER BY 
    sm___employee_skills.date DESC
```

**But I want it by And**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sm___employees.id,
    sm___employees.employee_code,
    sm___employees.leaving_date,
    sm___employees.name_of_employee,
    sm___employees.position,
    sm___employees.rating,
    sm___employees.entry_date 
FROM 
    sm___employees 
JOIN 
    sm___employee_skills 
ON 
    sm___employees.id=sm___employee_skills.employee_id 
WHERE 
    ((sm___employee_skills.skill_id=1 AND sm___employee_skills.ans LIKE '%MBA%') 
    **AND**
    (sm___employee_skills.skill_id=5 AND sm___employee_skills.ans IN (3)))
    AND 
    sm___employees.rating IN (1) 
ORDER BY 
    sm___employee_skills.date DESC
```

When am using first query with OR of MBA or 3,  It gives me result for both which is correct as per OR operation
I want only those records which are having MBA AND 3 which gives me blank records when there are records available with this comparison

So please help me to resolve this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post some sample data relevant to your tables

Comment: Does this mean that the data are in two different records and you want the conditions to match across these records (e.g. find employees who have both records)?

Comment: table1-sm___employees= employee_id,rating  ::::: table2-sm___employees_skills=employee_id,skill_id,ans,date :::: these two tables am using and from which am coparing skill_id,ans from es table and rating from employees table

Comment: @Prajakta: You do notice that you haven't answered Shadow's question, don't you? Q: "Do you want employee records that have two particular skill records associated" A: "I have two tables". What the heck? And do you understand what M Khalid Junaid has asked you to do? You have not been able to explain properly what you want, so showing some sample records for both tables and the expected result rows could have helped.

Answer (score 1):

To start with: DISTINCT often indicates a badly written query. This is the case here. You are joining records only to dismiss them later. If you want employee records, then select from the employee table. If you have criteria on the skills table check this in the `WHERE` clause. Don't join.

Then the WHERE clause looks at one row at a time. So neither `skill_id = ... AND skill_id = ...` nor `skill_id = ... OR skill_id = ...` can work for you. You must look up the skills table twice:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  employee_code,
  leaving_date,
  name_of_employee,
  position,
  rating,
  entry_date
FROM sm___employees 
WHERE rating IN (1) 
AND id IN
(
  SELECT employee_id
  FROM sm___employee_skills
  WHERE skill_id = 1 AND ans LIKE '%MBA%'
)
AND id IN
(
  SELECT employee_id
  FROM sm___employee_skills
  WHERE skill_id = 5 AND ans IN (3)
);
```

And here is a way to look up skills just once:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  employee_code,
  leaving_date,
  name_of_employee,
  position,
  rating,
  entry_date
FROM sm___employees 
WHERE rating IN (1) 
AND id IN
(
  SELECT employee_id
  FROM sm___employee_skills
  WHERE (skill_id = 1 AND ans LIKE '%MBA%')
     OR (skill_id = 5 AND ans IN (3))
  GROUP BY employee_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill_id) = 2 -- both skills
);
```

It seems strange though that you consider `ans` to be a string in one place (`ans LIKE '%MBA%'`) and a number in another (`ans IN (3)`).

**UPDATE:** If you want to sort by skill date, you should consider by *which*  skill's date. For this to happen, you would join, but not join the skills table, but the skills aggregate result. E.g.:

```
SELECT 
  e.id,
  e.employee_code,
  e.leaving_date,
  e.name_of_employee,
  e.position,
  e.rating,
  e.entry_date
FROM sm___employees e
JOIN
(
  SELECT employee_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
  FROM sm___employee_skills
  WHERE (skill_id = 1 AND ans LIKE '%MBA%')
     OR (skill_id = 5 AND ans = 3)
  GROUP BY employee_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill_id) = 2 -- both skills
) s ON s.employee_id = e.id
WHERE e.rating = 1
ORDER BY s.max_date;
```

Comment: Any reason why you use `IN (3)` somewhere and `= 3` somewhere else ?

Comment: @Rafalon: `IN (3)` was copied from OP's query. `= 3` is what we'd usually use for one value only.

Comment: That's what I thought, I was quite puzzled about the use of `IN` for one value, so I was wondering if there was any performance issue behind this. Thanks !

Comment: Tried your first code which has sub queries used instead of JOIN but that's also not working its also resulting same like my query

Comment: No, you are mistaken. Your AND query cannot return rows. Your OR query returns the employees having skill 1 or 5 or both. My queries return only employees having both skills 1 and 5.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  sm1.id,
  sm1.employee_code,
  sm1.leaving_date,
  sm1.name_of_employee,
  sm1.position,
  sm1.rating,
  sm1.entry_date 
FROM sm___employees sm1 
LEFT JOIN sm___employee_skills sm2 ON sm1.id = sm2.employee_id
WHERE ((sm2.skill_id=1 AND sm2.ans LIKE '%MBA%') 
  AND (sm2.skill_id=1 AND sm2.ans=3)) 
  AND sm1.rating IN (1) 
ORDER BY sm2.date DESC;
```

Comment: Please consider using code blocks to format your answer, it will be much more readable

Comment: I've formatted the code from you. However, this is still just code, no answer. *Why* should the OP try this? What flaw have you detected in their query? How have you got around this issue? As far as I see it, your query can't work, because `ans` cannot be 3 and match '%MBA%'  at the same time.